# Fiori Mobile - Unhandled Error: 'bPackagedBuild' is undefined (SAP Build Project)

Tags: mobile, sapui5, sap-web-ide

Just last week I exported a zip file from SAP Build (the prototyping tool) and imported this into SAP WEB IDE.

I simply choose 'Fiori Mobile' and 'Build Packaged app' from the menu to create a mobile app.

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work anymore.

The error returned is

Unhandled Error: 'bPackagedBuild' is undefined

The full error in the log is : (hat) no template id is found, and the project seems not created from WEB IDE. As such, Fiori mobile does not officially support it. The app may encounter issues if you continue with a build.

Why has SAP stopped support?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this has never been supported. The cloud-based build from the `Fiori Mobile` context menu always had a white list for supported template types, and it happens to cover most Web IDE application templates. Are you perhaps confusing the cloud-based build with the local [Hybrid Application Toolkit](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide_hat/frameset.htm)? This tool allows you to run builds from your Web IDE and does have those restrictions. The builds are run locally on your machine, and you will need to set up the corresponding software in order to be able to use it.

**Edit**: I stand corrected. Unsurprisingly, this is supposed to work, and the use case has been documented e.g. [in a recent blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/05/04/an-end-to-end-developer-experience-with-sap-build-sap-web-ide-sap-fiori-mobile/). As Thomas pointed out below, I believe that you are experiencing a temporary issue.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not correct. I've been using the context menu for a while now. I haven't needed to install any additional software locally, fiori mobile just builds it for me. What's worse is that kapsel seems to have been depreciated in the WEB IDE templates so I can't use them anymore either.

Comment: Just to confirm, my old project I imported from build is still there, and I can still access the apk file generated from it. SAP have changed something obviously because I can no longer deploy a build from here.

Comment: Sorry, this was Product Management lingo: I meant to say, I do not recall seeing requirements on this specific scenario, so it might well be possible that it was working "by chance". However, I have double-checked and it seems to be a temporary issue indeed.